# Flutter Lottie: Change Stroke and Content Color

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, lottie

I am having trouble changing color of a lottie animation stroke and elements inside other elements.

I am using this flutter package to implement Lottie:
https://pub.dev/packages/lottie

Lottie File:
https://lottie.host/f948b752-c810-49e7-80b0-9897f992f48f/ILKE0jRVvc.json

Public Link:
https://lottiefiles.com/118721-3d-box

The shade element is a stroke for which I am not able to change color.

After effects file:
https://bafybeieytnbxl4rqy2obamn4urezwsdnldq7btv5gkoxg6cr7gfoxcztuu.ipfs.dweb.link/1378-3-d-flat.aep

I am use following code since this keypath works for everything else:

```
LottieBuilder.network(
        'https://lottie.host/f948b752-c810-49e7-80b0-9897f992f48f/ILKE0jRVvc.json',
        delegates:   LottieDelegates(
          values: [
           ValueDelegate.color(
          ['3d_box', '**'],
          value: Colors.red
        ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

What keypath should I use for strokes?
Also What should I use for contents of an element like: `box`, which is content of `3d_box` (check file for reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ValueDelegate.color` goes through the Lottie file in hierarchical order and selects the colors to change as specified in the `keyPath` list. This order is labeled in the code below as *layer*, *group* and *shape name* for better understanding.

For example, if you wish to select all the groups with name `3d_box`, all the layers should also be selected by using '**' for the layer name in the key path.

```
delegates: LottieDelegates(
  values: [
    ValueDelegate.color(
      // keyPath order: ['layer name', 'group name', 'shape name']
      const ['**', '3d_box', '**'],
      value: Colors.red,
    ),
  ],
),
```

This approach also works to color several groups at once, provided they have the same group name in the Lottie file.